# How is $route object initialized?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I tried to access this.$route on created() hook, but as I log it to the console it always returns an empty object

```
{path: '/', name: undefined, params: {…}, query: {…}, hash: '', …}
fullPath: "/"
hash: ""
matched: []
meta: {}
name: undefined
params: {}
path: "/"
query: {}
redirectedFrom: undefined
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

I guess it is because the loading is asynchronous? Then how can it locate the path from the beginning ??

I tried to do this and it worked. I wonder if anybody could explain what happens under the hood.

localhost:8080/?server=BlackHole

```
// index.js
  {
    path: '/network-error',
    name: 'NetworkError',
    component: NetworkError
  },
  {
    path: '/:server',
  },
```

```
// App.vue
created() {
     setTimeout(() => {
      // △ Request to unreachable server
      if (this.$route.query.server == 'BlackHole')  
        {this.$router.push({ name: 'NetworkError' })}}, 1)},
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You have no catch-all route defined here

Comment: I have this one, does this count
 
`{path: '/:catchAll(.*)',`
`name: 'NotFound',`
`component: NotFound,`
`props: true},`

Answer (score 0):

When you'r on the `/network-error` route, the app is above that, so you can't say in the app *where are you in my app ?*

Because your application at this time `created` and `mounted` the view app and after go inside the route detected.

The good and normal practice is to fetch every route before like a middleware, inside your `router.js` or `routes/index.js` use this function:

```js
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  if (to.name === 'BlackHole') {
    next({ name: 'NetworkError' })
  }
  next()
})
```

This maybe doesn't not exactly match your redirect because i miss some information, but i think you understand what you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because the route load is an async process, I found a very quick solution here, just add this line of config to main.js:

```
router.isReady().then(() => {app.mount('#app')})
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6gT6qHtch8&ab_channel=VueMastery